# Manually setting JDK path for Android Studio

Tags: java, path, android-studio

How can I use a custom JDK path for Android Studio? I don't want to mess with PATH because I don't have admin rights. Is there a config settings file somewhere that allows me to set this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the project settings you can reach the jdk from there. On the standard windows keymap you can select the project in the project panel and hit F4. The jdk is on the project settings..

Comment: This is necessary to do after switching JDK. However, there is no indication anywhere in Android Studio of what the actual problem is. The build just fails silently.