# How to set JDK path correctly in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I am using Android Studio 1.4.1. when I tried to open an existing project, i received the follwoing error:

```
Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java  
executable. Tried location: C:\xxx\SDK\bin\java.exe
```

I do not know why Android Studion looks for the Java.exe in the SDK folder. the JDK path is specified as shown in the image

**image**:

[image]

This issue causes the all the classes of the App to be marked with a red circle with "j"letter.

Please let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually setting JDK path for Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764903/manually-setting-jdk-path-for-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to something like this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`.

Comment: i cant see any difference between the solution you provided and the image i posted...i did the same thing already

Comment: Environment variable and module setting is not the same thing. Fe. I can not even open Android Studio 2.1.2 with bad JAVA_HOME

Comment: but i cant figure out what do u suggest..because what you provided is exactly the same as what i posted in the image..would you please clarify further

Comment: I mean to set env variable, not some variable in Android Studio. https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Answer (score 0):

In android studio
go to file 
then choose PROJECT STRUCTURE
and go to JDK LOCATION
and choose current path of jdk
(e.g. /home/vishu/android-studio/jdk1.8.0_111)

if  you do not have jdk downloaded
use this link-
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
download according to your OS